# I can't get VirtualHost (Apache) to work for a Zend Framework project (in MacOSX)

Tags: macos, apache, zend-framework, virtual, host

I am trying to create a virtual host for a Zend Framework project, but it is not working.

I added the string "127.0.0.1 mysite.local" to the hosts file (/private/etc/hosts), and this is what I put in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public"

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted server, and then I try to access it in browser like: http://mysite.local:8888/, but it takes me to "htdocs" root, not to the Zend Project.

Am I missing something? Did I type something wrong? I'm using MacOSX, I tried putting port 8888 instead of 80 in the VirtualHost definition but it didn't work too.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to run it on a different port? Your vhost looks fine, so it should work with just http://mysite.local/

Comment: I solved it now! Port should be 8888, and it was not working too because of the APPLICATION_ENV, which was set to "development". Sorry to bother you, I am not used to these apache settings. Thank you anyway